# How to use category and subcategory in url without any fixed name?

Tags: php, codeigniter, router

I'm unable to make SEO friendly category based URLs in CodeIgniter :

Current url:

```
http://www.website.com/view/T-Shirt/round-neck
```

My route code:

```
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'Frontend/sub_sub_category/$1';
```

But i want to show like this:

```
http://www.website.com/T-Shirt/round-neck.
```

Comment: I've never used Codeigniter. But why don't you just remove `view/` in your route definition?

Comment: what is the view?, is it a controller or you're using some template engine?

Comment: view is just name of route url with Frontend controller @BILALMALIK

Answer (score 1):

try this:

your route should:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'product';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/product_category/product_sub_category';
```

You Will get:

```
http://www.website.com/T-Shirt/round-neck
```

get more help with refer link: **[codeigniter URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=route)**

also go with **[stack overflow link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142212/codeigniter-routing-helping)**

Comment: sir, if i use this code will show same page of  sub category. not solved sir
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] => this will show same page always due to this route

Comment: what is your default_controller?